# How to plot quadratic model?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, polynomial, quadratic-form

I have fit a polynomial `glm` in R with `x` and `x^2` as the predictor of interest.

```
m=glm(y ~ poly(x,2) + 
          continuos.control.var.1+ 
          continuos.control.var.2 + 
          categorical.var.3,  
          data=dfSubSample, 
          family = "gaussian)
```

The regression output suggests that the coefficients of both `x` and `x^2` are significant at p < .05.

I would like to plot this quadratic relationship between `y` and `x`. How do I do this for `x` given the other three control variables?

Comment: See the `predict()` function. You will need to create a data frame with your desired x, control values and then pass this data.frame for  something like: `predict(m, df, ...)`

Comment: Not sure what to do after predict()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample of your data here is a simple example.
The basic workflow is creating the dataset, fitting the data, making the prediction and then plotting:

```
#create fake data
x<- seq(0, 10, 0.2)
y<- x^2  - 1.25* x - 5 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.3)
dfSubSample <-data.frame(x, y)

#fit the model
m=glm(y ~ poly(x,2), data=dfSubSample, family = "gaussian")
summary(m)

#make the prediction, (need to pass a dataframe to the predict function
yhat <- predict(m, data.frame(x=seq(-1, 11, 0.4)))    
prediction <- data.frame(x=seq(-1, 11, 0.4), yhat)

#plot
library(ggplot2)
g<-ggplot(prediction, aes(x=x, y=yhat)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point(data=dfSubSample, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), color="red")
print(g)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can the same logic for yhat be used  with multiple independent variables? Can a subsample of original data be passed to predict rather than generating them as you do?

Comment: If you want to compare to the fitted variables to the original dataset, that information is stored in model and the predicted values are accessible with `m$fitted` and for the residuals use: `m$residuals`.  If you want to make a prediction at other conditions then yes, can use my procedure above to extend to multiple independent variables.